# ffmpeg output doesn't play on multiple devices

Tags: ffmpeg

*I have read the other stackoverflow posts regarding this topic so I am fairly certain this is not exact duplicate.*

ffmpeg exports a video that seems to only play on select players. I want to export a video that plays on iphone/mac/general players. I have seen the suggestions for the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` tag but this does not seem to work anymore - I read that Mac has since changed their systems that makes it not compatible anymore.

I am running:

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i screen%01d.png output.mp4
```

This all works fine and I can see the video by doing:

```
ffplay output.mp4
```

But I would like to be able to transfer this to mobile or general playback, any way to do this, ideally using ffmpeg? I'd rather not use two tools to do 1 job.

---

- Works on gmail
- Doesn't work on QuickTime Player
- Doesn't work on Flip Player
- Doesn't work on iPhone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of options is important. It should be,

```
ffmpeg -start_number 1 -framerate 4 -i screen%01d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```

Now pix_fmt is set as an output option. Originally, it was trying to force the input format, but since PNGs are images with metadata and not raw pixel data, th eoption had no effect. Additionally, for web use, it's good to also set `-movflags +faststart` as an output option.

Note that old versions of VLC couldn't play videos with framerate < 6. Could possibly be an issue with a few other players as well. Add `-r 8` as an output option to avoid that.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that order of operations mattered.

Comment: In this case, it's not the order of *operations* but where the option is placed. Options before an input affect how the input is decoded. But output pixel format is an encoding option so it goes before an output filename and after the inputs.